# implicit String to JsString

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Instead of creating a JsObject idiomatically like

```
Json.obj("foo" -> "bar")
```

it seems easier in my case to build one up with a

```
JsObject then += (String, JsValue).
```

The problem is a JsValue is required so something like

```
json += "foo" -> "bar"
```

will not compile, and need to be written as

```
json += "foo" -> JsString("bar")
```

How can you still use the implicit conversions that `Json.obj(...)` has? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given an existing `JsObject`

```
scala> Json.obj("foo" -> "bar")
res23: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"foo":"bar"}
```

If you want to add to it a name/value pair, you can do :

```
scala> res23 ++ Json.obj("john" -> "doe")
res24: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"foo":"bar","john":"doe"}
```

Or

```
scala> res23 + ("john" -> JsString("doe"))
res32: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"foo":"bar","john":"doe"}
```